# Programmatically Hide Keyboard Shortcut Bar iOS 13

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to *programmatically* remove the keyboard shortcut bar that appears at the bottom of an iPad when an external keyboard is connected.

There are plenty of posts and answers with "solutions" to this, but none of them work with the latest iOS. The closest solution was such:

```
UITextInputAssistantItem* item = [self inputAssistantItem];
item.leadingBarButtonGroups = @[];
item.trailingBarButtonGroups = @[];
```

All this currently does is remove the buttons on the left side of the bar. And this does nothing also:

```
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

---

How can I "programmatically" remove this bar??

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for using swift code.

You can try my idea:

1. change autocorrectionType of UITextField from .yes to no.
2. Get inputAssistantItem and change leadingBarButtonGroups and trailingBarButtonGroups to empty.

Source code example:

```
    tfSearchNameHiragana.autocorrectionType = .no
    let shortcut: UITextInputAssistantItem? = tfSearchNameHiragana.inputAssistantItem
    shortcut?.leadingBarButtonGroups = []
    shortcut?.trailingBarButtonGroups = []
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't seem to work - but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Following the existing answers didn't do the job for me (iPadOS 14.7.1). Instead of hiding the toolbar, I've got an empty (therefore useless) grey bar sitting on top of my onscreen keyboard, hiding valuable screen real estate, especially on an landscape home-buttoned iPad model.

I found out, that additionally to setting the two empty arrays you need to set the `inputAccessoryView` to `nil`. *Et voilà!* The bar above the keyboard completely disappears.

```
textField.inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = []
textField.inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = []
textField.inputAccessoryView = nil
```

You may think that setting the view to nil alone does the job, but as it turned out, this works only in combination with setting the empty arrays.

Comment: It works on my case, iOS14

Answer (score 0):

From InterfaceBuilder, change Correction to No:

[image: Text options]

Or, from source:

```
item.autocorrectionType = .no
```